# D3.js Cartesian distortion for x-axis only

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Been meddling with this for sometime now. I have a vertical graph in d3, what I want to do is create a function addDistortion() that references the present vertical graph and produces a Cartesian distortion using D3's fisheye.js. I am trying to achieve something like this>
    http://jsfiddle.net/fierval/f4hna/
where on mouse move there a distortion along the x-axis. I am trying to get the same type of distortion to work with my graph, but doesn't seem to work. Here is the work till now>

```
function addDistortion() {

var w = 1000;
var xfisheye = d3.fisheye.scale(d3.scale.identity).domain([0, w]).focus(w/2).distortion(3);
var barWidth = 12;

var t3 = d3.selectAll(".bar");
var t4;
console.log(t3);

//redraw();

t3.on("mousemove", function() {
    var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    xfisheye.focus(mouse[0]);
    redraw();
});

function redraw() {
     t4 = t3.selectAll("rect")//.data(mapData)
    .attr("width", xfisheye(barWidth));
}
}
```

live at> https://jsfiddle.net/akhiforu/o5r01zgm/3/

can some one help me figure out how to do this properly?